# File names changing during googledrive or dropbox sync'ing

Tags: manjaro, google-drive

when i copy/paste files or just move them from googledrive cloud their name's change to a long weird senseless sequence of characters.  Anyone knows how to fix it?

i have googledrive mounted in my notebook.  I just drag or copy and paste a file like below:

File name:
`test.txt`

after moving it from cloud to my pc:
`hduweewu`

I am using manjaro.

Thanks

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and show us filenames before and after, and explain how you're seeing the filenames, what directory,...

Comment: Just did. happens with any directory..

Comment: "any directory"? Not responsive. Actual full paths to the files would let me confirm/deny my hypothesis that you're looking at the underlying filesystem. In a terminal window, use `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld` to investigate

Comment: no such file or directory

Comment: any directory:  i can see my googledrive files, i copy one of them, paste on my documents, or downloads, or desktop, whatever, always the same: names goes crazy.